# Set width of td depending of the content inside them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I set the width of a `<td>` in a table to be equal to the content of the largest `<td>` in that column and in the same time have the table with width of a 100%.

My table is sometimes less than 100% width because i have some columns with no content in them because i have not assigned any values to them.

Comment: you just need to set the width to `100%` and the rest will be automatically optimized

Comment: Add your code so that we can find the issue in your code to come out.

Comment: @Praveen that will be very difficult because I am trying to override the CSS of the list tables in Odoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set the width of the table to `100%` and the width of `<td>` will change automatically

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial MoctezumaCentro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you look at the example i posted just now and tell me what i might be missing.

Comment: you want to make the same width of the TDs in a row, not a column, right?

Comment: I would just like the width of the table to be a 100% and the content of the <td> to be shown and with ... in the end.

Comment: well, you have to write your code, I can't do anything without seeing what's happening